# Create columns using tab char in text output, based on text width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, email, text

Let's say I have a list of product numbers, product names, and quantities, which are getting dumped into text output. Let's say all three fields are variable length, and I don't have the benefit of a fixed-width font in the output. Is there any way to reliably calculate the number of tabs to insert in each row to create consistent columns? This is ultimately going into an email via javascript, so assume no HTML usage in the output.

The closest I got was looping through the list, recording the maximum string length of each field, and writing a function to approximate the number of tab chars based on the difference between the current strlen and max strlen. Assumes 6 chars is roughly equivalent to a tab. It gets me close, but it crumbles at the extremes.

```
function cTab(strLen, col){
    var i, tabs = "";

    for(i=1;i<=Math.floor((max[col]-strLen)/6)+2;i++){ tabs+= "\t"; }

    return tabs;
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/UA6QF/

I briefly contemplated mapping each common keyboard character to a "width value" (e.g `A` would be `1`, `i` would be `0.5`), and calculating tabs based on width sums instead of strlens, but that seemed really heavy and a bit extreme.

PS: Please don't ask how it came to this, I really wish we could build something more competent. It is a long, sad story, and a cautionary tale for future generations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any system you use will be unreliable for regulating font spacing in email, particularly because different machines may not even have the same font. You're limited by the fact that different systems will have different fonts, which are all, as I'm sure you know, differently sized.
Unless you use HTML emails you're pretty much out of options, I believe unless you calculate the "maximum size" for the largest font. But even then, window width can completely blow that away.